# Weird HTML & JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, defined

I keep getting an error saying my function "key" is not defined. Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
        <script language="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onkeypress="key()">
        <p>Money: <p id="money">0</p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
int money = 0;

function key()
{
    money += 1;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
}
```

Comment: Get that Java out of your JavaScript!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: `text/javascript` is not a *language* supported by the browser's scripting engine, so the browser will ignore the script.

If you were writing HTML 3.2 you would say:

```
language="javascript"
```

If you were writing HTML 4 you would say:

```
type="text/javascript"
```

It is 2014, so write HTML 5 and don't specify a type or language attribute at all.

---

Second, `int money = 0;` is invalid JavaScript. (You seem to be trying to write Java.). So the script will throw an exception and stop at that point.

Use `var` to declare variables (of any type) in JS.

```
var money = 0;
```

Comment: +1 for writing html5 and not specifing a language attribute at all

Comment: @enguerranws It shouldn't. `int` is not a valid keyword in JavaScript. As _Quentin_ explained it's `var`...

Comment: Yes, that's why I was suprise that @sanoj00 said it was working before Quentin posted the edit.

Comment: @friedi posted it too, earlier.

Answer (score 6):

```
var money = 0;
```

instead of

```
int money = 0;
```

Comment: Still saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined"